# How do I cast /copy from a char array so that I may store it in a char pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings, stdio

I'm working on a project that involves reading and /or writing from a text file. Currently the only data I'm attempting to extract from the text file are names. My goal is to be able to store specific names in a character pointer array such that `Char[n]` will have a name assigned to it for any given n in the array.

The problem I seem to be having is that I'm setting my character pointer element to another character array where I'm storing the read value from the text file.

For example, if I read a name from the text file and set `Name[]` equal to that name then later set `Char[0] = Name` then `Char[0]` will always change when `Name` does.

I've attempted to write the string directly to `Char[0]`, for example, but then my program crashes just after I attempt to read and store the value. Therefore, I've resorted to this convoluted route of assigning a separate character array to the name I scan and setting one of my elements to it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * inf = fopen("UserNames.txt", "r");
    char User[125];
    int err, TopNameNumber = 10;
    char *UserNames[TopNameNumber];

    if (inf == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("ERROR: No name file detected."); 
        return 0; 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < TopNameNumber i++)
    {
        //This reads from my .txt file
        err = fscanf(inf, " %s", User);

        if(err == EOF)
            break;

        //This shows me what user was read from the text file
        printf("User read %d: %s\n", i+1, User); 

        //Program assigns the pointer address of User to Names[i]
        //This is where I'm having trouble
        UserNames[i] = User;
    }

    for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        // This always just prints out the last name read from the .txt file 
           for every name
        printf("Name #%d: %s\n", c, UserNames[c]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've been at this for a few days and I've found some interesting avenues which could possibly solve my problem, such as copying the string with `strcpy()` function, or perhaps casting `User` to something. All to no avail so far, however.

I would appreciate any advice as to what you think is the best solution to pursue if the solution isn't obvious here. I would like to avoid doing everything character by character, but I suppose I would be willing to in the long run.

I apologize for perhaps an unclear question, this is my first time asking one, and I'm just trying to give as much context as possible :)

My code compiles with no warnings or errors as of right now.

Comment: It is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, not `int main()`. Never use `*scanf()` without a length specifier to `%s`-fields.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the `main` function! Just got a bit sloppy. I can understand that having length specifiers would be helpful however I'm trying to use this code to read arbitrary lengths of names in the text file. I forgot to mention that the names are separated by new lines if that helps :)

Comment: "I'm trying to use this code to read arbitrary lengths of names in the text file." Then you can't use fixe-size arrays.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < TopNameNumber i++)`  This does not compile!  It is missing the `;` between the second and third parameter

Comment: regarding: `for every name`  This does not compile!  It is missing the leading `//`  When posting code, please copy/paste rather than typing the code again.

Comment: When calling any of the C library functions (for instance: `fopen()` ) always check that the operation was successful and if not successful, then use `fprintf( stderr, "...")` or `perror( "..." )` to pass the text to `stderr`, then cleanup and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("ERROR: No name file detected."); `  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and (when available) should include the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The easiest way to accomplish all the above is to call: `perror( "ERROR: No name file detected." );`

Comment: regarding: `err = fscanf(inf, " %s", User);  if(err == EOF)`  There are other reasons the call to `fscanf` can fail other than EOF`.  Suggest using: `if( fscanf(inf, " %s", User) != 1) {` which checks if the call was not successful and therefore, catches all the failures.  BTW:  using the input format specifier `%s` and/or `%[...]` should always be given a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  This allows for the (always appended) NUL byte and never overflows the input buffer, which would result in no undefined behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the blatant error I see is here:

```
    //Program assigns the pointer address of User to Names[i]
    //This is where I'm having trouble
    UserNames[i] = User;
```

reusing the same buffer for *all* usernames isn't going to fly. On the other hand, you cannot use `strcpy` because no memory is allocated. You can use `strdup` which allocates & copies the string.

```
UserNames[i] = strdup(User);
```

or for the purists (since `strdup` isn't strictly in the standard):

```
UserNames[i] = malloc(strlen(User)+1);
strcpy(UserNames[i],User);
```

As a security side-note, since the buffer is 125 bytes long, I suggest limiting the input it can accept to 124+nul-termination:

```
err = fscanf(inf, " %124s", User);
```

Of course, you need to deallocate the strings when no longer used, or you'll get memory leaks if your program doesn't quit or is part of a bigger code.

```
free(UserNames[i]); // in a loop in the end, when no longer needed
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot! I never thought about it like that. I knew my code was going to `User` since I set it equal to it. But I guess I couldn't quite figure out how to transfer the information from `User` to `UserNames`. Thanks for the help! You all have been great! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for a separate `char[]` for each name you read from the file.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *inf = fopen("UserNames.txt", "r");
    if (inf == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: No name file detected.");
        return 0;
    }

    int err, c = 0;

    const int TopNameNumber = 10;
    char UserNames[TopNameNumber][125];

    for(int i = 0; i < TopNameNumber; i++) {
        err = fscanf(inf, " %124s", UserNames[c]);
        if (err == EOF)
            break;

        printf("User read %d: %s\n", c+1, UserNames[c]);
        ++c;
    }

    fclose(inf);

    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf("Name #%d: %s\n", i, UserNames[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *inf = fopen("UserNames.txt", "r");
    if (inf == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: No name file detected.");
        return 0;
    }

    char User[125];
    int err, c = 0;

    const int TopNameNumber = 10;
    char* UserNames[TopNameNumber];

    for(int i = 0; i < TopNameNumber; i++) {
        err = fscanf(inf, " %124s", User);
        if (err == EOF)
            break;

        printf("User read %d: %s\n", c+1, User);

        UserNames[c] = malloc(strlen(User) + 1);
        if (UserNames[c] == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed.");
            break;
        }

        strcpy(UserNames[c], User);
        ++c;
    }

    fclose(inf);

    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf("Name #%d: %s\n", i, UserNames[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        free(UserNames[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```